# ajax form submit redirect like a not ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that I use to submit a form with a attachment file

```
$("#career_form").submit(function(e){
    var this_current = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData(this_current[0]);
    var url = this_current.attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        data: formData,
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function(){  },                   
        success: function(response){
            if(response === true){
                alert("successfully sent");
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

but the form keeps redirecting me to its destination file "url in the action" like it wasn't an ajax submission but if I replace the 'data' argument with

```
data: $(this).serialize();
```

it works (ajax submit), any ideas, help, suggestions, recommendations?

Comment: is there any error in your browser console

Comment: there's no error and If ever there's an error, I could not catch up because the form redirects (the url in the action attribute, acting like a none ajax form).

Comment: in the console check the preserve log checkbox and then submit form so that logs are not deleted on new page request

Comment: Hi i accept with `Anoop LL`'s answer, and also once check this.. i think may be u gave `<input type="submit">`, give it as `<input type="button">`... coz i did the same mistake few days back...

Comment: @phpfresher: I tried his, but I got this error instead "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Comment: Hi, i think the `e.preventDefault();` should  be after `$("#career_form").submit(function(e){`, not at the bottom..

Comment: @RahulPratapSingh: thank you for the suggestion, i see an error "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Comment: @phpfresher: hello, any reason why I should put the "e.preventDefault()" after the "$("#career_form").submit(function(e){"? I believe "e.preventDefault()" should be inside the "$("#career_form").submit(function(e){" function as "e.preventDefault()" halt/hold the default behaviour of the form "not natively submit".

Comment: Hi, even am not sure about it.. Actually i thought like, all the code will be executed first and then it goes to `e.preventDefault();`... here we have to prevent the default behaviour first and then we have to execute the code.. I dunno may be its correct/wrong.. I just tried..

Answer (score 2):

give that e.preventDefault(); at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Exactly. The preventDefault(); has to be the first instruction to be given. Then you can start elaborating any other stuff with the form data

Comment: and I got this error "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Comment: the above post is the latest. Please refer on it.

Comment: give processData: false  after cache

Comment: anyhow you need to give e.preventDefault() at the beginning else the form automatically invokes the action specified

Comment: not true, the `e.preventDefault` works no matter where it is placed. In this example the only reason why it doesn't is that there is an error before so that the `e.preventDefault` is never called

Answer (score 0):

jQuery trys to transform your data by default into a query string, but with `new formData` it throws an error.

To use formData for a jquery ajax request use the option `processData` and set it to false like:

```
 $.ajax({
        url : url,
        data: formData,
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
    processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){  },                   
        success: function(response){
            if(response === true){
                alert("successfully sent");
            }
        }
    });
```

Thats the reason why it works with `serialize`, but not with `formData` in your example.

The `e.preventDefault` works correctly, but if there is an error before it will not work. By placing the `e.preventDefault` at the top of your function it will allways prevent the action, no matter if there is an error in later code or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `var formData = new FormData(this_current[0]);` in your code and use the below line:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#career_form"));
```

Also, if you are using multipart form to send files in your form, you need to set following parameters in your ajax call.

```
  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
```

Hope this helps. See more about using formData **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)**.

Comment: so any ideas, help how to put it on the data argument in the ajax function (how to compact the attachement along the other form inputs to the new formData)?

Comment: Doing some more research I found that I was wrong in my previous answer. So, I have updated my answer. Please have look and sorry for giving wrong answer previously.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#career_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
    fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
    $.ajax({
        url: "change-status.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response){
                alert("successfully sent");
            }
        }
    });
});
```